# Building a docker container with multiple conda envs

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As a novice to the technology I have only a basic knowledge regarding how to build and deploy a docker so i was hoping someone could provide some help.

The situation is the following:

I need to create a docker container with two conda environments and then I want to call a command line from my native os (linux).

Firs i created two conda envs:

```
env-a.yml:

conda create --name env-a
conda activate env-a
conda install -c bioconda samtools
conda env export > env-a.yml

env-b.yml:

conda create --name env-b
conda activate env-b
conda install -c bioconda samtools
conda env export > env-b.yml
```

Next I build my docker container

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM continuumio/miniconda3
     COPY ./env-a.yml /opt/
     COPY ./env-b.yml /opt/
     RUN conda env create -f /opt/env-a.yml
     RUN conda env create -f /opt/env-b.yml
     RUN echo "source activate env-a" > ~/.bashrc
     ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH
```

my build :

```
docker build -t test ./
```

and now i run it

```
docker run -it test
(env-a) root@1c44fcc2e83d:/#
```

looks good…
now i want to mount a location from which my files are read and execute two pipelines each calling tools from different  environment:

```
docker run --init -v /media/data/home/booby/test/:/opt/ test /bin/bash -c "source activate env-a && env view -h /opt/my.bam > /opt/my.sam && source activate env-b && samtools view -b /opt/my.sam > /opt/my.bam"
```

but when i mount a volume (-v) , it seams I lose access to my conda envs.

```
/bin/bash: activate: No such file or directory
```

what would be the proper way to set this up?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the contents of `/opt/` in the container with the contents from `/media/data/home/booby/test/`. Mount it in some other directory - for example to a subdirectory of `/opt` as shown below as shown below

```
docker run --init -v /media/data/home/booby/test/:/opt/sam /bin/bash -c "source activate env-a && env view -h /opt/sam/my.bam > /opt/sam/my.sam && source activate env-b && samtools view -b /opt/sam/my.sam > /opt/sam/my.bam"
```